# Run PHPPowerpoint on Linux Server

Tags: php, phppowerpoint

Im trying to run a project that uses phppowerpoint on a linux server. Its working ok on windows. But when I put my project online, the same way it is on my wamp server, its doesnt work. It seems like its having problems with case sensitive. The thing is that I didnt change any of the original files of this library. Im calling the names of the files right, but everytime I run it, it gives me problems with requires, includes, paths, etc.. Do I need to change something to make it work on a linux server? 
This the first error that it shows:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'PHPPowerPoint/Slide.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /storage/.../phppowerpoint/PHPPowerpoint.php on line 30

I think that the problem is with this line

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');`

The way this `set_include_path` is, it wont work on a linux server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as you said **case sensitive** issue...

This is the case: In the `Classes folder there is a file and a folder

1. Folder: `PHPPowerpoint`
2. File: `PHPPowerpoint.php`

Notice that in both of them the word **point** has a lowercase letter **p**

Then in the code, all the references are going to **PHPPowerPoint**

Notice that the word **Point** has an uppercase letter **P**

This is the origin of all the errors.

So All you need to do is to rename those two folder and file in the `Classes` folder and make the letter **P** for the **Point** to the uppercase...

You do not have to change the code and make them lowercase, because in the library itself also all the references are to **PHPPowerPoint** with capital **P**

To sum thing up, you have to have these file and folder in the `Classes` folder:

1. Folder: `PHPPowerPoint`
2. File: `PHPPowerPoint.php`

Hope you would find it useful...